# How to round up the_field PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rounding

How can I round up the below code in Advanced Custom Fields code in Wordpress?

```
<?php the_field('estimate'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**`ceil(...)` rounds up**.

```php
echo ceil((int)get_field('estimate'));
```

Comment: Also should note the use of `get_field` here returns the value so you can manipulate it whereas `the_field` renders the value of that field including any filters registered for it.